# ACRA form key in new google Docs

Tags: google-docs, acra

Where can I find form key of Google spreadsheet? I need it to use in ACRA crash reporter.
I'm unable to find it in current version of Google docs.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using GoogleDocs to receive ACRA crashes anymore.
There are many alternate services available.

See https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Backends

Comment: They are well documented on the ACRA web site https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Backends